# How to append variable with anchor element href link in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I append the variable to the href link ?
I tried something like -

```
 $scope.downloadFile=(fileName,id)=>{
 <a  href='https://downloadFile?fileName='+fileName+'&id='+encodeURIComponent(id)></a>;
 }
```

This is not working.

Comment: Can you give us any context?

Comment: Your ' is placed wrong

Comment: @MaximilianDolbaum where exactly ?

Comment: @LarsFlieger I have a dropdown and a button to download file selected from the dropdown. For that purpose I need to make a href to take dynamic id and fileName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using template literals will help make it more readable, but put the backticks on the outside of the whole string. Additionally, when you use arrow functions you *can* omit the `return` statement, but only if you avoid using curly braces. Your function wasn't returning anything

```
$scope.downloadFile = (fileName,id) => `<a href="https://downloadFile?fileName=${fileName}&id=${encodeURIComponent(id)}"></a>`;
```

Here's a sample in plain JS

```js
const downloadFile = (fileName,id) => `<a href="https://downloadFile?fileName=${fileName}&id=${encodeURIComponent(id)}"></a>`

console.log(downloadFile("THEFILE","THEID"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), it helps making strings more understandable

Try this one:

```js
 $scope.downloadFile=(fileName,id)=>{
 <a  href=`https://downloadFile?fileName=${fileName}&id=${encodeURIComponent(id)}`></a>;
 }
```

Comment: This is not working !!

Comment: @Amara What is the href in the url?